# Why I cannot get css from jquery?

Tags: jquery

I want get css value from boxLeft and boxTop, but in console is shown this error `boxes[i].css is not a function`.

How can I make it working?

```
function checkPlayerClicks() {
    board.click(function(e) {
        var boxes = $("." + boxClassName);

        for (var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
            var boxLeft = parseInt(boxes[i].css("left"), 10);
            var boxTop = parseInt(boxes[i].css("top"), 10);
        }
    });
}
```

In js I can use `getComputedStyle()`, but here I'm lost.

Thanks for help.

Comment: `boxes[i]` returns a DOM element, not a jQuery object.

Comment: As Felix mentioned, you have a DOM element. You can either call `$(boxes[i]).css()` or just `boxes[i].getComputedStyle()` as you have mentioned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

boxes[i] doesn't return a jQuery object, so you need to wrap it in a jQuery selector:

```
var boxLeft = parseInt($(boxes[i]).css("left"), 10);
var boxTop = parseInt($(boxes[i]).css("top"), 10);
```